# PowerBI - Run Rate with Start and End Dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of data that looks like this:

| OneTime (T/F) | PLSavings | ImplementationDate | EndDate | LengthofBenefit | MonthlyBenefit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | 337,500 | 2/10/2021 | 11/14/2024 | 1 | 337,500 |
| False | 100,000 | 8/1/2021 | 7/31/2024 | 35 | 2,857.14 |
| False | 8,000 | 1/1/2021 | 12/31/2021 | 11 | 727.27 |

I have a date table as well.  I am able to calculate the cumulative monthly total, but am struggling how to account for the end date as the Benefit should drop off. Likewise, if OneTime = True, the total should just apply to the monthly implementation date.  Using the sample data above, the results should look like this:

| Month & Year | Monthly Benefits | YTD Benefits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| January 2021 | $727.27 | $727.27 |
| February 2021 | $338,227.27 | $338,954.54 |
| March 2021 | $727.27 | $339,681.81 |
| April 2021 | $727.27 | $340,490.08 |
| May 2021 | $727.27 | $341,136.35 |
| June 2021 | $727.27 | $341,863.62 |
| July 2021 | $727.27 | $341,590.89 |
| August 2021 | $3,584.38 | $345,175.27 |
| September 2021 | $3,584.38 | $348,759.65 |
| October 2021 | $3,584.38 | $352,344.03 |
| November 2021 | $3,584.38 | $355,928.41 |
| December 2021 | $3,584.38 | $359,512.79 |
| January 2022 | $2,857.14 | $2,857.14 |

In case it's helpful, I have been playing with a couple methods for the cumulative total to try and build off of that:

```
VAR MinDate = MIN(SCM_BenefitTracker[ImplemenationDate])
VAR MaxDate = MAX(SCM_BenefitTracker[EndDate])
VAR DateList = 1
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(SCM_BenefitTracker[Monthly Benefit]),
    FILTER('Date Table - Imp', 'Date Table - Imp'[Date] <= MaxDate &&
    'Date Table - Imp'[Date] >= MinDate)
)
```

```
VAR CumulativeTotal = CALCULATE( [Total PL Savings],
                        FILTER( ALLSELECTED( 'Date Table - Imp' ), 'Date Table - Imp'[Date] <= MAX ('Date Table - Imp'[Date] ) ) )
RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the approach with table variables and generate.
You should be aware of memory usage if you have really huge dataset.

```
MonthlyBenefits = 
var _CurrMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[YearMonth])
var _virt = SUMMARIZE(GENERATE(SELECTCOLUMNS('OneTime',"ImplementationDate", 'OneTime'[ImplementationDate], "EndDate", 'OneTime'[EndDate], "MonthlyBenefit",'OneTime'[MonthlyBenefit], "OneTime", [OneTime (T/F)])  , FILTER( CALCULATETABLE( ALL('Calendar'[YearMonth], 'Calendar'[Date] ),   _CurrMonth = 'Calendar'[YearMonth]),'Calendar'[Date] >= [ImplementationDate] && 'Calendar'[Date] <= if([OneTime], [ImplementationDate],[EndDate]  ))), [YearMonth],  [MonthlyBenefit])
return

CALCULATE( SUMX(FILTER(_virt,   _CurrMonth = [YearMonth]), [MonthlyBenefit]))


MonthlyAccuBenefits = 
var _CurrMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[YearMonth])
var _virt = SUMMARIZE(GENERATE(SELECTCOLUMNS('OneTime',"ImplementationDate", 'OneTime'[ImplementationDate], "EndDate", 'OneTime'[EndDate], "MonthlyBenefit",'OneTime'[MonthlyBenefit], "OneTime", [OneTime (T/F)])  , FILTER( CALCULATETABLE( ALL('Calendar'[YearMonth], 'Calendar'[Date] ),   'Calendar'[YearMonth] <= _CurrMonth ),'Calendar'[Date] >= [ImplementationDate] && 'Calendar'[Date] <= if([OneTime], [ImplementationDate],[EndDate]  ))), [YearMonth],  [MonthlyBenefit])
return

CALCULATE( SUMX(FILTER(_virt,  [YearMonth] <= _CurrMonth ), [MonthlyBenefit]))
```

[image]